# How to pass an id parameter to grid (from a callbck) in ext js so that I'll be able to get only one output?

Tags: extjs

I have this and I can see that I can get the ID that I want but I don't know how to pass it to he grid panel, so that the grid panel will only show that unique row.

```
 callback : function(a,b,c){
            console.log(Ext.decode(c.responseText).root);
            console.log(Ext.decode(c.responseText).root[0].ID);
             grid.getStore().reload();
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for **grid.getStore().filterBy(...)**

```
grid.getStore().filterBy(function(rec, id){
    //your logic here. probably something like 
    //if(id===id_of_row_to_include) return true; else return false;
});
```

Use this *after* your store has loaded.